# Output showing in debug console, but now terminal vsCode

Tags: java, debugging, visual-studio-code

Since yesterday, whenever I run a code it debugs fast and shows the result in the debug console and not the terminal. I've been using VScode for a while now, but never had this issue. Any fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you set the debug console as the default option.
You can type "ctrl+shift+P" and then choose launch.json.
Delete the line "console": "internalConsole"

Answer (score 0):

If you downloaded the code runner, this condition will happen. You can find "run in terminal" in the settings and choose it. IF not, you can download it and select it, too. Hope helpful.